# Track loyalty points that expire, using PHP

Tags: php, logic

I am trying to improve a code that I haven't written yet. Somebody else wrote a code (in some other language) but it has a bug, so I'm trying to write something similar without the bug but I can't think of a way that is neat.

This is what is going on.
We have a loyalty card system where people get points for purchases.
They can then use those points to purchase things.
What is causing a problem is a rule that says that points expire after 6 months.

The code that is now being used, but has a bug, simply says something like:

```
$currentPoints = array_sum($lastSixMonths);
```

where $lastSixMonths is an array containing all positive and negative points in the previous months.
Perhaps something like this:

```
$lastSixMonths = array (
'2018-01-10' => -1000,  
'2018-02-10' => 10, 
'2018-03-10' => 10, 
'2018-04-10' => 10, 
'2018-05-10' => 10);
```

In that case $currentPoints = -960, which should be impossible.
The reason being that if I were to take the last 7 months, I would get something like this (in most cases this is a very simplified version):

```
$lastSevenMonths = array (
'2017-12-10' => 1000,
'2018-01-10' => -1000,  
'2018-02-10' => 10, 
'2018-03-10' => 10, 
'2018-04-10' => 10, 
'2018-05-10' => 10);
```

Let's say that today is July 1, 2018. 
Last 6 months would then be Jan 1 - Jun 30, 2018.
Last 7 months would be Dec 1, 2017 - Jun 30, 2018.

So on Dec 10th, a customer gained a 1000 points, and used them on Jan 10th, when they had not expired yet. But today, the Dec transaction has expired, but not the Jan transaction.

How can this be done?

Keep in mind that a customer can use however many points he wants to, so he might have used only 2 points or any other amount in January (up to 1000), so I can not just mark the transactions in Dec and Jan as "completed".

The only way I can think of doing this is to take every negative transaction and even them out with all positive transactions, 6 months in the past.
I haven't written out the code, but it feels like it will be very time consuming, if I do it that way, as I have to do that for millions of transaction lines and tens of thousands of customers, and each line looping through every day of the past six months, beginning at day 1.

Any suggestions of a better method?

Comment: This belongs on the code review stack exchange

Comment: You won't be able to implement this unless you track the gained points separately from the ones spent. For example, let's say a client gained 900 points in January yet spend 1200 points; those 900 should be taken into account until June, yet you won't see them in your record, only balance of -300.

Comment: @raina77ow But even if I track them separately the calculation will always be complicated. In your example, I would need to know if the 1200 spent points were using up points gained in January, December, November or whenever so I can determine which points are available for each date.

Comment: @emsimpson92 CR is for improving the design of *working* code, this code doesn't work.

Comment: Do you ever allow their points to become negative? If not, you can just ignore the negative entries before the first addition in the six month array.

Comment: It won't help. Again, for example one can gain 900 and spend 600 (making a month balance +300, yet actually spending most of the points accumulated earlier). This +900 should stay for 6 months still.

Comment: You're saying they expire six months after some part is used, not after they're earned?

Comment: @Barmar The points expire after they are earned.

Comment: @emsimpson92 Isn’t code review for code that works, but could work better?  This code doesn’t work at all and he’s asking how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Since any points earned more than 6 months ago have expired, you can treat it as if their balance was zero six months ago. Any purchases before the first award in `$lastSixMonths` must have been made using points that have expired, so you can ignore them. So if you have

```
$lastSixMonths = array (
'2018-01-10' => -1000,  
'2018-02-10' => 10, 
'2018-03-10' => 10, 
'2018-04-10' => 10, 
'2018-05-10' => 10);
```

you can remove any initial negative entries:

```
foreach ($lastSixMonths as $date => $amount) {
    if ($amount >= 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        unset($lastSixMonths[$date]);
    }
}
```

Then you can use `array_sum($lastSixMonths)` to get their current balance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What if I had a '2018-05-15' => -5 in there. Your code would just unset it. That wouldn't work.

Comment: This doesn’t work. Dec 30 I earn 10 points. Jan 5 I earn 5 points.  Jan 20 I spend 5 points. Feb 5 I earn 10 points.  July 1 rolls around and says I have 10 points, but I should have 15.

Comment: @Andri It wouldn't unset the 2018-05-15 entry, because `break` ends the loop when it finds the first positive value.

Comment: @StephenR You're right, it doesn't account for the fact that the balance was 15 when the 5 were spent on Jan 20. The real solution probably requires keeping track of "lots" that were earned, and subtracting from the oldest non-expired lot when spending.

Comment: Yeah, I m working on something like that @Barmar. Have a workable version now that I am going to try. Just getting the data now from a web service to a database, before I can try it out. Just fetching the data is taking some time, I'm afraid running the code will take even longer. Since I'm on shared hosting, any code that runs over 5 minutes will get a 503 error, so that might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears any answer would have to distinctly record when points are earned and when *those particular points* are spent.

So for each record of points, you might have the following fields:

“points”, “spent”, “date_earned”

Then when the person spends points, it marks off the oldest (still valid) records of points as spent.  You may have a record that looks like this:

`Points: 10, 
Spent: 7, 
Date Earned: 2018-03-15`

Then you look for points earned in the past six months, and subtract the total spent from the same records. Something like (pseudo-SQL):

`SELECT ( sum(points) - sum(spent) ) AS points_remaining FROM loyalty_points WHERE date_earned > [date six months ago] AND user_id=?`

The tricky part is marking off points as they are spent — as spending 150 points would likely span several records of points earned, going from oldest to newest.